# How to show row number information on rich datatable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to show the following text on the footer of my table:

```
Showing 11 to 20 of 51 entries
```

But I can't find a way to do it. I didn't find any vars in the footer that give me those variables easily.

I also tried to create a class that inherits from `ExtendedDataModel` and kept the values there.

I got the number of the row from the `sequenceRange` in the `walk` method. But, apparently, the footer of the table is rendered before the `walk` method being called, which resulted that the info on the bottom of my page was outdated by one request.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

By the way, I'm using JSF 2.1 and RichFaces 4.3.0 Final.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [datascroller](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf?c=scrollableDataTable&tab=usage) feature of rich faces:

**Update 1**

The scroller has a default layout which you might not want. But you can customize it. see Scroller Facets Usage tab in this [link](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf?c=scrollableDataTable&tab=usage). Copying here:

```
<f:facet name="pages">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <h:outputText value="Page "/>
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{dataScrollerBean.scrollerPage}" 
                                onchange="#{rich:component('ds')}.switchToPage(this.value)">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{dataScrollerBean.pagesToScroll}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                            <h:outputText value=" of #{pages}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
```

Comment: The dataScroller just shows the page number and the buttons to go to the next page and the previous. (You linked to richfaces 3.3.3 example **[here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataScroller&sample=simpleScrolling&skin=blueSky)** is the example for data scroller 4.3.0. I'm showing that in my page, but I also want to show the text based on the page and number of rows shown per page.

Comment: try customizing the scroller. i updated my answer. not sure if it will work for 4.3 but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:
[Datascroller](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTableScroller.jsf?tab=scrollerfacets&cid=669327)

This example shows the number of rows in a datatable in datascroller based on size mentioned in rows attribute of dataTable.